# How to try webGPU in Firefox Nightly now in fall of 2022?

Tags: javascript, firefox, webgpu

I learned about the new webGPU standard becoming a real thing few weeks ago and of course I want to try to play with that.

I read in multiple sources that Firefox Nightly has partial support if you enable it in `about:config`.

I tried it, however none of the online demos worked even after all that. Trying to create the webGPU interface in the console produced an error as well, just as if I was running normal firefox release.

Could you please provide detailed steps to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, `Chrome Canary` is the browser with the best support for the WebGPU standard, and Chrome plans to have WebGPU support in an official release in May 2023.

To enable WebGPU in `Firefox Nightly`: Type `about:config` in the address bar, set `dom.webgpu.enabled` and `gfx.webgpu.force-enabled` to `true`.
[image]

To enable WebGPU in `Chrome Canary`: Type `chrome://flags` in the address bar , set `Unsafe WebGPU` and `WebGPU Developer Features` to `Enabled`.
[image]

Comment: This doesn't work on Firefox release (109.0) or Nightly (110.0b2) on Linux (Lubuntu).